# DC/DC Pi output filter inductor gets hot and causes voltage drop

Tags: filter, dc-dc-converter

On my PCB I have a pi-filter as shown below at the output of a DC/DC converter. The DC/DC has an output voltage of 19.5V and will supply a max current of 1.3A. The switching freuqency of the converter is 250kHz. C1, C2, and C3 are ceramic caps. Target ripple is 50mV (i know, not achievable with current design).
Inductor physical size is 4.2 x 4.2 x 2mm and max DC resistance is 16mOhm.

The issues are the following:

- Output voltage is only ~17V
- Large voltage ripple (400mV at no load, more with load)
- Inductor gets hot (80°C or more)

So I tried shortening the inductor and the result was way better. I still have a too large ripple but at least the output voltage reaches the expected 19.5V (a little bit less but okay). I am aware that I have to change the filter design and especially C1 may be larger (or a second 10uF added in parallel). However, I have the following questions for the current design:

1. Why is the inductor causing a voltage drop of about 2V?
2. A 47uF electrolytic cap for C2 and C3 will have a larger ESR instead of the currently used cermaic caps, which however will have beneficial impact on the resonant behavior of the filter. Is this assumption correct and is it advisable?
3. Is my way correct that I have to choose an inductor with a higher current rating and also increase the inductance value to 470nH in order to get the cut-off frequency down?

[image: Pi-Filter on DC/DC output]

EDIT:

C1,C2,C3 are rated for 25V. I know that C1 should be rated higher (e.g. 50V).

Here is the measurement after the filter at about 0.9A load:

[image]

Comment: You haven't mentioned the DC resistance of either inductor; nor the physical size.

Comment: I have now added this information.

Comment: What's the waveshape before and after the filter? Is your feedback before or after the filter?

Comment: waveshape is sine-like, 250kHz. It's a flyback converter with an AUX winding. Feedback is sampled on primary side from that AUX winding.

Comment: Have you tried with a different inductor? It could be that this one doesn't have an air gap, which means the DC current drives it to saturation. If you remove the caps and check the current waveform, if it's saturated, the waveform should no longer be triangle, but curved upwards triangle. Actually, the caps don't need to be removed, just probe the current through the inductor (series resistor, additional loaded winding).

Comment: Actually I have an update: the voltage drop does not occure across the inductor. The inductor is just influencing the control loop - which is sampled from aux winding in transformer. So i guess the problem is more complex than i thought 

Comment: I assume you designes the entire converter. Maybe ypu should post the entire circuit.